# nested EJS tag. Not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, ejs

just a simple question but i cant find anything on it on google.

So here it is,

Why this doesn't work?

on the 1st line, the last **'%>'** turns white [image]

This is from my NodeJS js file. when i render the "loginuserprofile" i passed the userProfile variable to EJS 
[image: This is from my NodeJS js file]
and i'll get an error of

**Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".**

i cant use nested <% %>?

Thank you!

Comment: just remove inner tags?

Comment: i can't remove inner tags because the userProfile variable is from my nodejs server that i passed in this EJS.. i've edited my post. you can see where is my userProfile came from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not use nested `<% %>`

You need to use just `<% if (userProfile.facebook.length === 0) { %>`

Like

```
<% if (userProfile.facebook.length === 0) { %>
    <h1>No Facebook!</h1>
<% } %>
```

Comment: oh my god i didnt think i can do that. thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to rewrite ejs expression tag again inside if as if statement itself is in expression tag and will render the template variables without any problem.