# what is this happening .It showing me this error Could not find matching close tag for "<%"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

EJS template code,Where the hell is the problem!!!

```
<ul>
<%if(<%=itemslist[0]%>!=""){%>

<%for(let i=0;i<=<%=itemslist.length%>;i++){%>
<li> <%=itemslist[i]%> </li>
<%}%>  

<%}%>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nested EJS tag. Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210362/nested-ejs-tag-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ejs blocks inside of ejs blocks:

```
<ul>
<%if(itemslist[0]!=""){%>

<%for(let i=0;i<=itemslist.length;i++){%>
<li> <%=itemslist[i]%> </li>
<%}%>  

<%}%>
 </ul>
```

Comment: how do i pass this ejs variable value <script>
    function editfunc(){
   var editval=prompt("What do you want to edit?");
    }
    </script> to node post req

Comment: @HAZIQ I don't understand how this new question is related to your main question.

Comment: @HAZIQ Then you should create a new question.

Comment: kindly see if u coud help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/64270501/13028541

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with this style but I would guess it is the nesting of the <% %> tags.
Does it work if you remove the <%= %> like below?

```
  <%if(itemslist[0]!=""){%>
    <%for(let i=0;i<=itemslist.length;i++){%>
      <li> <%=itemslist[i]%> </li>
    <%}%>
  <%}%>
```